# How to pass a return int to another class as String?

Tags: object, printing, private, public, bluej

I have this assignment for university and have spent hours trying to get the various parts working within the Tutors guidelines (It would be easy if I could change the array to public :( ).

Anway I have an AccountList class with an array called accounts and I need to use this method

**AccountList Class**

```
  public int getNumberOfAccounts()
   {
       return accounts.size();
   }
```

In my text based user interface to return the accounts.size as a string, here is what I have so far but I can't work out how to convert that accountList.getNumberOfAccounts return to a string within this class so that I can println it.

**AccountTUI Class**

```
public void getNumberOfAccounts()
    {

        accountList.getNumberOfAccounts();


    }
```

Here is the full set of code.

**AccountTUI Full**

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class AccountTUI here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class AccountTUI
{
    AccountList accountList = new AccountList();
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);



    public AccountTUI()
    {

    }


    public void menu()
    {
        int command = -1;
          while ( command != 0 )
  { 
      displayMenu();
        command = getCommand();
        execute( command );
    }
}

    private void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("\n Please Select An Option");
        System.out.println("To quit enter 0");
        System.out.println("To add an Account enter 1");
        System.out.println("To remove an Account enter 2");
        System.out.println("To get the number of Accounts enter 3");
        System.out.println("To show a single Account enter 4");
        System.out.println("To show all Accounts enter 5");


    }



    private int getCommand()
    {
        System.out.print ("Enter command: ");
        int command = myScanner.nextInt();
        myScanner.nextLine();  // handle eol
        return command;
    }

    private void execute( int command)
    {
        if ( command == 0 )
            quitCommand();
        else
        if ( command == 1)
           addAccount();
        else
        if ( command == 2 )
             removeAccount();
        else
        if ( command == 3)
             getNumberOfAccounts();
        else
        if ( command == 4)
            showAccount();
        else 
        if ( command == 5)
            showAllAccounts();

        else {

           unknownCommand(command);

        }
    }




    public void addAccount()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("\n Enter First Name \n");
        String firstname = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter Second Name \n");
        String secondname = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter Account Number \n");
        String accountnumber  = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter Street \n");
         String street  = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter Town \n");
         String town  = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print ("Enter Postcode \n");
         String postcode  = keyboard.nextLine();

        accountList.addAccount(new Account(firstname,secondname,accountnumber,
                   street,town,postcode));

    }


    public void getNumberOfAccounts()
    {

        accountList.getNumberOfAccounts();


    }

    public void quitCommand()
    {
        System.out.println("\n Application is closing");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public void removeAccount()
    {
    }

    public void showAccount()
    {

    }

    public void showAllAccounts()
    {
       System.out.print('\u000C');
        accountList.getAllAccounts();
        System.out.println("");



}

    public void unknownCommand(int command)
    {
        if (command < 0 || command > 5) {
            System.out.print('\u000C');
        System.out.println("Unknown command.");

    }
}


}
```

**AccountList Full**

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * This is the AccountList class provide for students
 * in Blackboard at the start of the homework
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class AccountList
{
   private ArrayList<Account> accounts;    

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class AccountList
    */
   public AccountList()
   {
       accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
   }

   public void addAccount(Account account)
   {
       accounts.add(account);
   }

   public int getNumberOfAccounts()
   {
       return accounts.size();
   }

      public boolean getAccount(String accountNumber)
   {
       int index = 0;
       for (Account account : accounts)
       {
           if (accountNumber.equals(account.getAccountNumber()))
           {
               account.printAccountDetails();
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               index++;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }    


   public void getAccount(int accountEntry)
   {
       if (accountEntry < 0)
       {
           System.out.println("Negative entry: " + accountEntry);
       }
       else if (accountEntry < getNumberOfAccounts())
       { 
           Account account = accounts.get(accountEntry);
           account.printAccountDetails();
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("No such entry: " + accountEntry);
       }
   }

   public void getAllAccounts()
   {
        for(Account account : accounts)
        {
            account.printAccountDetails();
            System.out.println();
        }
   }

   public void removeAccount(int accountEntry)
   {
        if(accountEntry < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Negative entry :" + accountEntry);
        }
        else if(accountEntry < getNumberOfAccounts())
        {
            accounts.remove(accountEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No such entry :" + accountEntry);
        }
   }

   public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
   {
        int index = 0;
        for (Account account: accounts)
        {
            if (accountNumber.equals(account.getAccountNumber()))
            {
                accounts.remove(index);
                return true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return false;
   }


   public int search(String accountNumber)
   {
       int index = 0;
       for (Account account : accounts)
       {
           if (accountNumber.equals(account.getAccountNumber()))
           {
               return index;
           }
           else
           {
               index++;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }    



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert an `int i` to a `String`, you can just use

```
String.valueOf(i);
```

So you could just modify your method like this:

```
public String getNumberOfAccounts()
{
   return String.valueOf(accounts.size());
}
```

or you could leave the method as it is and use `String.valueOf()` when you want the `String` representation to put into your user interface.

BUT you say that you want to use `println()` on it. Note that `println()` will also accept an `int` directly, so there's nothing to stop you just writing

```
System.out.println(getNumberOfAccounts());
```

even if `getNumberOfAccounts()` returns an `int`.

Also, you should note that you're not using an array (or if you are, you're doing it wrong). There is no `.size()` method on an array; but there is on an `ArrayList`, so I suspect that's what you're using. The equivalent for an array is `arr.length` (with no `()` because it's a field and not a method).

Comment: I tried
`public String getNumberOfAccounts()
{
   return String.valueOf(accountList.accounts.size());
}`. 


but it says that accounts has private access in AccountList
and yes you are correct it is an arraylist :)

Comment: @RyanConway where are you defining this? If you're defining it in `AccountTUI` then you just want `return String.valueOf(accountList.getNumberOfAccounts())`. This will make it use the already defined `.getNumberOfAccounts()` method of `AccountList`.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you very much for the help! 
This is what I used in the end.

 `public void getNumberOfAccounts()
{
     String numberOfAccounts = String.valueOf(accountList.getNumberOfAccounts());
     System.out.println(numberOfAccounts);
}`

Comment: @RyanConway That should do it :) Well done for getting it working. Btw I'd also be tempted to change the method you've created to `printNumberOfAccounts()` rather than `getNumberOfAccounts()`, because `get...()` sounds as though it's returning something.

Comment: Ah that is because of the way the Tutor has worded it. The code we are writing is not the best in terms of standard haha.

Method - getNumberOfAccounts
Comments - Return the number of accounts in a formatted String 
e.g. “We have 7 accounts.”

Comment: @RyanConway Ah, you're printing it rather than returning it! Looks like you want to change the return type from `void` to `String`, and then `return numberOfAccounts` rather than `System.out.println...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
public String getNumberOfAccounts()
{
return (""+accounts.size());
}
```